# Design a Core Data Model for the behaviour of a football coach

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, core-data, database-design

I want to build a Model in Core Data that will save the Behaviours of a football coach during a match at a specific instant. 
What I have is a total of 30 behaviours grouped in 4 categories.

I thought to create 2 Entities:

- Session (nameS, dateCreation) -> It's the Match
- Behaviour (nameB, category, timing)

The Relationship I think is a one-to-many relationship (One Session can have multiple Behaviours).

Is it the right thing with Core Data ? Can you share your ideas ?

PS: Sorry for my English !

Thank You ^_^

Comment: Yes, you're correct: One session can have multiple behaviours. You merely need to make your behaviours an NSSet before storing in relation to the session.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! So to make my behaviours an NSSet, do I have to group all the instance of the behaviour obj ? Is there a method to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are on the correct lines with 2 entities and a relationship. Your names are very generic, which may support the future well if you want to use this for other things.

Make sure that the relationship goes in both directions (has an inverse).

When you generate your managed object subclass in Xcode it will add properties and methods for you. As you are adding new behaviours, just add them one at a time. Then, later, when you need them you can either get the `NSSet` from the `Session`, or you can query the data store for them (particularly useful if there are a lot of behaviours or you only want ones with a specific name or within a known time period).

Comment: So, if I want to store a Session and crete another session or many different Sessions for every match, can I ? Thank You ^_^

Comment: Yes, each `Session` will be separate in the data store and have a distinct set of `Behaviour`s in its relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Better I answer here than the comments.

Once you have your CoreData set properly, a method will be available to `addDataObject:` This can be used on an instance of your behaviour data, and will store it in an NSSet using the previous method.

Be warned, last I checked, there was an issue with this method and it won't work properly so you'll have to override it. To do this, create the following method in your `Session.m` header

```
- (void)addDataObject:(BehaviourData *)value
{
    NSMutableOrderedSet* tempSet = [NSMutableOrderedSet orderedSetWithOrderedSet:self.data];
    [tempSet addObject:value];
    self.data = tempSet;
}
```

`self.data` needs to be an `NSOrderedSet` that you will define in `Session.h`.